# Would a trans revenant be able to go through with a medical transition?

Tags: skills, world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

As the title suggests, I'm wondering if a revenant who is transgender would be able to go through with a medical transition if they had the opportunity and wanted to?

I would have thought so, but I did notice these listed traits:

> Like normal ghouls, revenants store vitae in their body to be used for healing, Disciplines, and temporarily increasing physical attributes. Like a ghoul, their flesh is preternaturally tough and they can soak lethal damage.

So, although I do still think hormones should work fine, now I'm wondering if their capabilities with that healing and level of durability would actually interfere with any desire for a potential op and make that not doable?

Or are those vampiric traits weak enough for this still to be successfully managed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Surgery Like Any Other

There are many situations throughout the World of Darkness where characters who can soak Lethal damage want to go through surgery. The simplest example would be benefiting from medicine for faster recovery of wounds. And as far as I remember, throughout the various books I have encountered, there are no statements that would prohibit Lethal-soakers to benefit from medicine purely because of their ability to soak Lethal. (*Vampires specifically* are prohibited from changing their bodies because they revert every 24 hours, but that's not the same thing.)

Similarly, while blood healing is very good for healing 'mere' Health Levels, I remember that healing limbs tended to be a harder process that one is unlikely to just do accidentally (caveat lector: this may have changed in newer editions).

Thus, **it is likely that the increased toughness would not preclude surgical modification, though it probably would make things harder**, such as requiring more forceful use of scalpels and needles (then again, reportedly surgery is already an activity not for the weak).

## Better Living Through Vicissitude and Rituals

If the above is deemed too much of a hurdle, there are two alternative ways of achieving permanent biological changes that are good enough *even for Vampires*: the Tzimisce Discipline of Vicissitude, and the Tremere Thaumaturgy rituals that allow circumventing the effects of Kindred blood for the purposes of reversions.